# Can I create record in Ember without the record name

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, post, ember.js

My Backend Rails API consumes POST requests in the form of

```
{
    "name": "Mark White",
    "email" : "mark@xyz.com"
}
```

Have tried this in Postman and this creates a record successfully.

In my ember frontend, Im using the following code to create a new record, from a form input:

*app/routes/addUser.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
        addUser(){
            let formData = {
                "name": this.controller.get('name'),
                "email": this.controller.get('email')
            };

            let newUser = this.store.createRecord('user',formData);
            newUser.save();
       }
  }

});
```

which generates the request as

```
{
  "user": {
    "name": "Mark White",
    "email" : "mark@xyz.com"
  }
}
```

which my backend is not prepared to handle and throws an error.

Any way I can quickly conform to the json format that works for me in Postman.

Answer (score 1):

When the question is along the lines with the "How can I change my payload to server for it to be in a certain format?" then you should have a look at [customizing a serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/).

But it looks like for solving your problem you might wanna take the [standard JSON Serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_jsonserializer); in your `app/serializers/application.js` just type the following:

```
import JSONSerializer from '@ember-data/serializer/json';

export default class ApplicationSerializer extends JSONSerializer {
  // ...
}
```

Note that it's for the Ember.js v4, according to your example you're using a bit older version so just adjust the syntax accordingly.